# Return results of a selector in setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, return-value

JS newbie here, sorry for dumb question in advance.

I am trying to gather all options from a select element and base the available options in another select element off whatever was selected in the first select element. I get all the options of a select element after waiting 1 second because those options are derived dynamically and aren't there to query immediately. The problem is that I don't know how to return `allNameOptions` so that I can use it in the following `change` function. I have tried a return statement but for some reason this returns the value `3`. No idea where that's coming from.

Current code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var allNameOptions = $('#cipAreaNames option');
}, 1000);

$('#printStateAbbrev').change(function () {
    $('#cipAreaNames option').remove()
    var selState = $('#printStateAbbrev option:selected').prop('value');
    var availOptions = allNameOptions.filter('.' + selState);
    $.each(availOptions, function (i, j) {
        $(j).appendTo('#cipAreaNames');
    });
});
```

What I tried (and edited `allNameOptions` to `names` in the change function):

```
var names = setTimeout(function () {
    var allNameOptions = $('#cipAreaNames option');
    return allNameOptions;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You should look into `Promises`.

Comment: Returning any value from a `setTimeout()` handler is pointless, because nothing will pay attention to the value.

Comment: "because those options are derived dynamically" - can you expand on this or provide the code?

Comment: defining variables in a scope and also needing to learn what asynchronous means.

Comment: @Zenoo - I decided to go with a Promise. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `allNameOptions` variable outside your function, in global space, without value. Like just `var allNameOptions;`. Next you can give it a value in one function and use it in another.